# Split table to gain performance?

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

```
+----+------+------+
| ID | USER | QUOTE|
+----+------+------+
```

My table was ok, it was fast and site was working well, but, now my table have a bit over 19.000.000 records, and it is really slow.

I think of something like: Create 4 separate tables with "only" 5.000.000 records, and when next table exceeds 5.000.000 records, to create next one, and so on, creating one more table every 5.000.000 records, which is happening really fast in last 2-3 months. Is there a way for me to connect them. They will be the same, same three columns, but, how to load them to act as one table?

Thanks in advance, if it is possible... :)

Comment: What query does your site use against that table?  There are things that can be done to make it faster.

Comment: If only there were some sort of way to use the database to write an index of some kind, or maybe even split a table up into certain parts...partitioning, maybe? Bah, that's just a pipe dream!

Comment: Well, I am doing three separate queries... I am loading last 50 entries, (SELECT * FROM uQuotes ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 50) on index page, then, I am doing search by user (SELECT * FROM uQuotes WHERE user='whatever'), and I am doing one random one, where I take one random number between one and COUNT of my table, and select only it by ID. Forgot to mention that ID is KEY... :)

Answer (score 2):

I would advice to use a single table with appropriate partitioning. For more details around partitioning, please refer: [MySQL Partitioning Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-types.html)

Comment: Thanks, on answer, but... How? We are talking about all different auto_increment ID, with more than 1.000.000 different USERs and every quote is unique... :) I am not sure if I understand how to use partitioning?

Comment: @DekiB It depends on your usage pattern. For example, if you tend to use recent data frequently then you may want to introduce the date column (created date) and use the same in partitioning and your retrieval queries. If you could provide more details around your data and the usage pattern, I would try to suggest an appropriate partitioning strategy.

Comment: @DekiB: As another example, if you could classify the users in some groups, you may want to introduce the user group and use the same as partition strategy.

Comment: On index page, I am showing last 50 entries, and I also have two scripts, one that is loading one random row (random quote), (rand between 1 and COUNT()) and one that is searching all quotes of one single user (I wrote SQL codes in a comment on my question). I basically have three pages running those codes, and one more page that is loading data from database based on ID. That one part works fine.

Comment: Well, I guess I can ask them in their user profiles to enter DOB or at least country they live in? :) But that is against my strategy to keep all simple as it can be... :)

Comment: @DekiB: Since your operations seems to be around user ID, I would advice to use some kind of user grouping for partitioning. If your user base is static (or rarely being changed, in that case you would need to re-partition), then you may want to use the use ID itself as partitioning column.

Comment: But, again, most of my visitors are in range of maybe 5-6 countries and in range of 10 years of birth or 120 different month groups of those 10 years...

Comment: @DekiB: I believe only birth month will give you 120 different values, which means you are virtually getting 120 sub table as oppose to 4 you wanted to create.